# GitHubからSpresense SDKを取得したが、dnnrt_hand_signが含まれていない

Tags: spresense

初心者で申し訳ありませんが、どなたか助けていただけると幸いです。

雑誌「Interface2019年1月号」を見ながらSpresenseでhand sign認識を進めており、GitHubからSpresense SDKを取得したが`dnnrt_hand_sign`がありません。ファイルは一体どこにあるのでしょうか。

GitHubのSpresense SDKをダウンロードしたリンクです。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense

examplesフォルダの中にdnnrt_hand_signファイルがあるとInterface誌には記載されていました。

Comment: 参考にした雑誌は「○○年××号」といった情報があると、運良く該当号を持っている人や、webサイトで試し読みが公開されていた場合に手助けしやすいかもしれません。

Comment: この記事 [Sony SPRESENSEでのhand-sign認識とCameraのPreview書き出し](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54870/26370) と類似でしょうか。他には [3.3. DNNRTライブラリ](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/developer-guide#_dnnrt%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA) に手順が、[Sony Spresense AI hand sign recognition](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/sony-spresense-ai-hand-sign-recognition) の記事にサンプルコード(の一部?)があるようです。

Comment: ご指摘、編集ありがとうございます。>>cubuckさん　　　　　　　　　　その記事と類似しています。ArduinoIDEでやっていないのでそちらでも挑戦してみたいと思います。>>kunifさん

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まったく同じものかどうかはわかりませんが、次のリンクにスケッチが丸ごとありました。

https://github.com/takayoshi-k/algyan_spresense_ai_hands_on/releases/download/tmp_version/rps_sample.zip

LCDのドライバなどもありますので、そのまま動かせると思います。

この資料は、ここから引っ張ってきました。

https://algyan.connpass.com/event/128666/

ニューラルネットワークコンソールの資料もあるので、参考になると思います。

Comment: スケッチのコンパイル、書き込み等、すべてがエラー無く進みましたが、カメラの画像がLCDに表示されず、真っ白な画面のままです。LCDとspresenseをつなげているピンが間違っているのか、よくわかりません。今現在このような接続をしています。SDO/MISO―12, LED―AREF, SCK―13, SDI/MOSI―11, DC/RS―9, RESET―8, CS―10, GND―GND, VCC―3.3V